# largest minimum difference of n elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search

Given an array A and number N.

Select N elements out of the array A such that the minimum difference between these N numbers are maximized. Return the largest minimum difference.

**Example1.** A = {1,2,4,8,9}, N = 3

**Output:** 3 *(because {1,4,9} maximizes the difference between these 3 numbers. 4-1=3, 9-4=5)*

**Example2.** A = {4,1,2,8,90,900}, N = 4

**Output:** 7

This is a question from a data structure course, I have struggled with this question for a whole day, I hope somebody can help me with it. Thank you!

Comment: Please try to demonstrate your effort by posting the solutions you have tried. Otherwise it looks like you are asking the community to do your homework assignments.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the array
2. For N=2 the output would be the values in [0] and [n] where 0 and n are indices of the array(n is the length of the array)
3. For N=3 0,n and n/2 (if n is odd you'll need to check which is better n/2 and n/2+1) and split the array to 2
4. For N=4, you need to check which "median" of the 2 arrays gives the best result.
5. I think you get it, always divide each half by 2.

Complexity: n*log(n) for the sort + N (for the check  + split)

Comment: This answer is unclear to me. Could you please present an example solution for a list of 10 elements? (A description of how would do, no need for code or pseudocode.)

Answer (score 0):

We can have a naive dynamic program with `O(n * log(n) * N)` time complexity, where `n` is the number of elements in `A`. Assuming the array is sorted, let `f(i, k)` represent the largest minimal difference in the optimal solution for `k` elements, chosen from the first to the `i`th element, then:

```
f(i, k) ->
  max(min(A[i] - A[j], f(j, k - 1)))

for all k - 2 ≤ j < i
```

Since `A[i] - A[j]` does not increase and `f(j, k - 1)` does not decrease as `j` increases, the smaller of either represents a unimodal function so we can binary search for the optimal `j` on each iteration.